# Does differentiablity imples the continuity of component functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis, is the following statement right?

"When $f$ is defined some neighborhood of $z_{0}$, if $f=u+iv$ is differentiable at $z_{0}$, then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ are continuous at $z_{0}$."

I can't find the related things above. Any help please.

Comment: No.  Differentiability at a point doesn't even imply continuity in any neighborhood of that point, let alone continuous partials.  That said, differentiability of a complex function in a neighborhood turns out to be a very strong condition indeed.

Comment: @btilly Surely being differentiable *at* $z_0$ implies being continuous *at* $z_0$. But I agree that it doesn't imply that the partials are even defined on a neighbourhood of $z_0$.

Comment: @Joppy Sure, differentiability at a point implies continuity at that point.  But that still doesn't imply continuity in any neighborhood of said point.  A classic example is the function $0$ on the transcendental numbers, and $x^2$ on the algebraic numbers.  It is differentiable at 0, but continuous at no point except 0.